# IntelliJ IDEA / Android Studio Plugin Navigate to Path / Expand Nodes in Device File Explorer

Tags: android-studio, intellij-plugin

I'm writing a plugin for Android Studio, and in part of it I want to be able to expand nodes in the Device File Explorer. I can retrieve devices easily, however I can't find any documentation to expand nodes in the Device File Explorer file tree.

I want to be able to programmatically push a path to the Device Explorer so that I can open the data path for my app, i.e. device/data/data/app.

[image: screenshot]

I was hoping to use DeviceExplorerController, but most of it is private (notably the DeviceExplorerView, which has the expandNode() function).

DeviceFileSystemService doesn't give me what I want, just the connected devices (I already retrieve devices through the AndroidDebugBridge class + addDeviceChangeListener()).

DeviceExplorerFileManager seems to only be for file management on the device & downloading locally, not doing UI operations.

Lastly I was looking at trying to get the Device File Explorer tool window itself [through this](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/tool-windows.html#accessing-tool-window), but I don't know what ID the built-in Device File Explorer has, and I have a feeling that it would lead me back to DeviceExplorerController.

The main reason I'm doing this is that I really want to avoid making my own file tree. If there's already a component that shows the info I want, why re-invent the wheel. Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but maybe the (tree variant) [file chooser component](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/file-and-class-choosers.html) can be useful?